# character tables and solubility

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, characters

I am currently going through a past exam paper for a group theory module and am unable to answer the following section of a question. The copy of my lecture notes doesn't seem to have a section on soluble groups but I would still like to know that if i am given the character table of this group [image]

The how would i determine whether the group is:

- soluble?
- Simple?
- Isomorphic to a subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$?

Any help would be much appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that number of the linear character is $1$ hence $\lvert G/G'\rvert =1$. Thus, $G$ is not solvable.

$g_2\in \ker \chi_4$ hence $G$ is not simple.

$\ker\chi_2=1$ hence $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb C)$.

Comment: +1, excellent answer. I have taken the liberty to do a little LaTeX editing.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Thank you very much :)

Comment: thank you @mesel for your answer, how did you conclude that the kernel of  $x_2 = 1$ ? the kernel is all the elements $g\in G$ such that $\rho(g) =1$ but where is this info on the table?

Comment: @PeterA: $Ker(\chi_2)=\{g\in G| \chi_2(g)=\chi_2(1) \})$. I think you are confused about the defination of kernel of character.

Comment: ah yes and this kernel is trivial and therefore isomorphic to the required subgroup? @mesel

Comment: @PeterA: Yes exactly.